# Why can't I use LINQ on ListView.SelectedItems?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I am trying to do use `.Select` extension method on `ListView.SelectedItems` which is `SelectedListViewItemCollection`, but `.Select` doesn't show up in intellisense.

I can use `foreach` on `SelectedListViewItemCollection`, so it must have implemented `IEnumerable`. I just checked on MSDN, and it certainly does. Then why can't the LINQ extension methods be used on it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The reason why is that SelectedItems is typed to a collection which implements IEnumerable.  The Select extension method is bound to `IEnumerable<T>`.  Hence it won't work with SelectedItems.

The workaround is to use the .Cast extension method to get it to the appropriate type and it should show up

```
ListView.SelectedItems.Cast<SomeType>.Select(...)
```

Comment: @Joan, I'm actually not sure.  I believe it's the underlying item and not ListViewItem.  I can't find the answer in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks Jared. Just wanted to make sure.

Comment: @JaredPar - Does that actually work for you or do you need myListView.SelectedItems.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select( ... )?

Comment: Thank you! I'd been looking for why a similar collection wouldn't work for freaking ever!

Answer (score 5):

It implements IEnumerable, not `IEnumerable<T>` - all LINQ queries are built around the generic `IEnumerable<T>` interface to allow type safety and generic inference - particularly when dealing with anonymous types.

You can use the following instead:

```
myListView.SelectedItems.Cast<ListViewItem>.Select( ... );
```

Comment: @LBushkin - Does that actually work for you or do you need myListView.SelectedItems.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select( ... )?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have "using System.Linq" at the top of your file?

Is it a strongly typed generic collection?  If not, you'll need to use the Cast<> extension method.